# Flicking geometries with OpenGL in Qt app

Tags: opengl, glsl, multithreading, qt

I have a Qt (5.9.1) app that on Windows many of the geometries I'm drawing flickers.  My problem description is vague because I'm at a complete loss.

Does anyone know if there's an issue with flickering on Windows with OpenGL (I think Qt uses [ANGLE](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/master/README.md) for OpenGL) that would be different than in Linux?  My app on Linux seems to work perfectly.

Specifically, my app draws LIDAR ground points (`GL_POINTS`), and boxes around objects (`GL_LINES`), and range marker circles (`GL_LINE_LOOP`).  These are all drawn to the same context.  I also set up double buffering.  All the rendering takes place on a render thread.  This is done in the style of [Scene Graph - Rendering FBOs in a thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinthread-example.html) (so, no Qt3D)

When the app starts, initially it seems fine, but after a couple seconds, different geometries, say, the boxes around objects, and/or the range marker circles, start flickering.  Although they're all on the same context, all of the same geometries (say the range markers) will flicker at the same rate (independent of the other geometry types), or all the boxes.

While this is happening, my measured FPS does slow down, but the flickering still occurs even when the FPS is up at 58+.  <strike>I've even inserted some `glFlush()`es and `glFinish()`es - no impact (either on FPS or flickering.)</strike>  **UPDATE** I must have made a mistake when testing `glFinish()` or something changed, because now `glFinish()` removes the flicking (and kills my FPS.)

The structure of my renderers is that I have one class that sets up the viewports, calls `glClear`, and then invokes `render()` on each renderer.  Those renderers have a buffer setup with vertex array buffers, I set some uniforms, and call `glDrawArrays`.  I don't think I'm doing anything unconventional. e.g.

```
opengl_safety_buffer_.bind();

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::Binder vaoBinder(&safety_vao_);
render_safety_program_->bind();

glLineWidth(safety_ranges_config_["lineWidth"].value<GLfloat>());
render_safety_program_->setUniformValue("col", vcol_);

glUniformMatrix4fv(render_safety_program_->uniformLocation("mvp"), static_cast<GLsizei>(mvp_matrices_.size()), GL_TRUE, reinterpret_cast<GLfloat*>(&(mvp_matrices_[0])));
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, opengl_safety_buffer_.CountVertices());

glDisable(GL_BLEND);

render_safety_program_->release();
opengl_safety_buffer_.release();
```

My vertex and fragment shaders are very simple.

I don't have great profiling data right now, but the little I do have shows that all my renderers combined don't take even half of the 1/60s time per frame I need.

The flickering started when I moved away from using a [Scene Graph Under QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) mixed with Qt3D, towards the threaded FBO example - so I figure there's nothing intrisic in my geometries that should be causing the flickering.

### UPDATE

Posting my top level render code.  Basically I have a loop that calls all my individual renderers sequentially, all on the same thread and on the same context.

Top level render code:

```
// ...

render_fbo_->bind();

// Clear
context_->functions()->glClearColor(0.039f, 0.055f, 0.10f, 1.0f);
context_->functions()->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Render only the faces closest to you
context_->functions()->glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
context_->functions()->glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

{
    // Configure out viewport (x,y, width, height)
    unsigned int i = 0;
    foreach (const auto v, scene_graph_->viewports())
    {
        // Make sure that the viewports cameras are updated
        v->camera()->calculatePosition();

        auto vs = v->paddedRect();
        context_->versionFunctions<QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core>()->glViewportIndexedf(i, vs.x(), vs.y(), vs.width(), vs.height());
        i++;
    }
}

foreach (const auto model, scene_graph_->models())
{
    if (model->isDirty())
    {
        model->renderer()->synchronize(model);
        model->dataSynced();
    }
    model->renderer()->render();
}

// Reset OpenGL state
context_->functions()->glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// We need to flush the contents to the FBO before posting
// the texture to the other thread, otherwise, we might
// get unexpected results.
context_->functions()->glFlush();

// FPS
recalculateFPS();

render_fbo_->bindDefault();
render_fbo_.swap(display_fbo_);

emit textureReady(display_fbo_->texture(), size_);
```

When I include `glFlush` `glFinish()` after `model->renderer()->render()`, I can see that some of my renders, specially my `GroundRenderer` is taking waay too much time (the black line represents the amx time for 1 frame):

[image: Profile of my renders]

So, my goal now is to figure out why `GroundRenderer` takes so much time.  It basically just writes to a large circular buffer.  I'm not experienced enough yet though to know what "*large*" is, but I haven't really observed a sensitivity to the specific size of the buffer (I cut it's size by a few orders of magnitude, and didn't see any real difference.)

Comment: You have a problem in the handling of multiple contexts and lack of synchronization. Post the details of your code treating the threads and contexts.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think I'm writing everything to the same context sequentially all in the same thread.  So I think it's really that a single renderer is taking up too much time.  I posted a graph showing the time taken by each renderer.

Comment: "// We need to flush the contents to the FBO before posting
// the texture to the other thread, otherwise, we might
// get unexpected results.
context_->functions()->glFlush();" glFlush tells the driver "now is a good time to start working with the command queue" which can be good for performance if there are large gaps between the last draw call and usage of the result such as buffer swap. You are not in sync after invoking it. If you want sync without locks checkout sync objects: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object

Comment: @Andreas I think you're right, but ultimately I'm pretty confident that my issue is that one of my renderers is simply taking too much time.  So if I properly sync, I won't see any flicking but my FPS will be cut in half.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that my renders are taking too long, which is "*solved*" with a `glFinish()`.  My understanding however is that `glFinish()` should only be used to debug, so this is not a solution, but it does point me in a better direction to ultimately solving my problem. (and tells me that my profiling attempts wasn't working as well as I thought.)

I've left this question up in case any one else experiences similar issues to me, but I want this answer to "close" this question as the question is pretty vague and I have a new direction to pursue.

Comment: Just an ammendment, very particular to the [Scene Graph - Rendering FBOs in a thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinthread-example.html), reversing the order of the `bindDefault` and the `qSswap` call seemed to make a huge difference.  The right there was the effective ultimate fix, but I don't understand it well enough to compose a proper answer based on it.